# How can I remove env directories from conda?

Tags: python, directory, anaconda, conda, environment

There are many directories included when I run `conda info` in cmd.

envs directories :
`C:\Users\Eduardo\.conda\envs`
`C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs`
`C:\Users\Eduardo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs`

In the current setting, new environements are created at `C:\Users\Eduardo\.conda\envs`, but I want them in `C:\Users\Eduardo\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs`.
How can I remove the first two environment directories from conda configuration ?

Comment: Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: I removed and reinstalled Anaconda for all PC users. My previous installation was for only  my user and that's the directory where the envs were stored.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your post and add the output of `conda config --get`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `conda config --remove envs_dirs /path/to/a/anaconda/envs` to remove an `envs_dirs` entry.

In your case :

```
conda config --remove envs_dirs C:\Users\Eduardo\.conda\envs
conda config --remove envs_dirs C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs
```